# $\int_{\mathbb R}|f(x)|^{2} dx <\infty \implies \sum_{m\in \mathbb Z}\int_{m-\beta}^{m+\beta}|f(x)|^{2} dx <\infty$?

Tags: real-analysis, hilbert-spaces, lp-spaces

Let $f\in L^{2}(\mathbb R),$ that is, $\int_{\mathbb R}|f(x)|^{2} dx <\infty,$ and $\beta>0.$

> **My Question**: Is it true that that: $\sum_{m\in \mathbb Z}\int_{m-\beta}^{m+\beta}|f(x)|^{2} dx <\infty.$ If yes, how to justify it?

Comment: If $\beta = {1 \over 2}$, maybe...

Comment: Yes, because you will cover every point in $\Bbb R$ a set amount of times, smaller than some constant that is roughly equal to $2\beta$ I would guess. The total sum should be smaller than $k\int|f|^2$ for some integer $k$ of the order of $2\beta$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$\int_{m - \beta}^{m + \beta} |f(x)|^2 \,dx$ is the same as $\int_{-\infty}^{\infty} \chi_{[m - \beta, m + \beta]}(x)|f(x)|^2 \,dx$, where $\chi_A(x)$ means the characteristic function of $A$. So 
$$\sum_{m \in {\mathbb Z}}\int_{m - \beta}^{m + \beta} |f(x)|^2 \,dx = \sum_{m \in {\mathbb Z}}\int_{-\infty}^{\infty} \chi_{[m - \beta, m + \beta]}(x)|f(x)|^2 \,dx$$
$$= \int_{-\infty}^{\infty} (\sum_{m \in {\mathbb Z}}\chi_{[m - \beta, m + \beta]}(x))|f(x)|^2 \,dx$$
Since $|\sum_{m \in {\mathbb Z}}\chi_{[m - \beta, m + \beta]}(x)| \leq 2\beta$ the above is finite whenever $\int_{-\infty}^{\infty} |f(x)|^2\,dx$ is finite.

Answer (score 2):

If $\beta \leq 1/2$, then
$$\sum_{m \in \mathbb{Z}} \int_{m - \beta}^{m + \beta} |f(x)|^2 dx
\leq \sum_{m \in \mathbb{Z}} \int_{m - 1/2}^{m + 1/2} |f(x)|^2 dx = 
\int_{\mathbb{R}} |f(x)|^2 dx < \infty$$

If $\beta > 1/2$, then let $K = \lceil \beta \rceil$. Since the interval $[m - \beta, m + \beta]$ is contained in $\bigcup_{k = -K}^{K} [m + k - 1/2, m + k + 1/2]$, it follows that
$$\int_{m - \beta}^{m + \beta}|f(x)|^2 dx \leq 
\sum_{k = -K}^{K} \int_{m + k - 1/2}^{m + k + 1/2} |f(x)|^2 dx$$
and so
$$\begin{aligned}
\sum_{m \in \mathbb{Z}} \int_{m - \beta}^{m + \beta}|f(x)|^2 dx & \leq 
\sum_{m \in \mathbb{Z}} \sum_{k = -K}^{K} \int_{m + k - 1/2}^{m + k + 1/2} |f(x)|^2 dx \\
&= \sum_{k = -K}^{K} \sum_{m \in \mathbb{Z}} \int_{m + k - 1/2}^{m + k + 1/2} |f(x)|^2 dx \\
&= \sum_{k = -K}^{K} \int_{\mathbb{R}}|f(x)|^2 dx \\
&= (2K+1) \int_{\mathbb{R}}|f(x)|^2 dx \\
&< \infty \\
\end{aligned}$$